# Does Joint::GetForce() return the sum of all forces on the joint?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Gazebo, does Joint::GetForce() return the last value specified by Joint::SetForce(), after clipping the value to the limit set by Joint::SetMaxForce()? Alternatively, does Joint::GetForce() return the sum of all forces on the joint? The comment in Joint.hh says only, "Get the force applied to an axis." I could not find any more documentation in http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-svn-html/classgazebo_1_1Joint.html. In fact, the documentation at that URL does not include Joint::GetForce(). I'm writing a Gazebo plug-in to steer a wheel on an autonomous vehicle, and want to know whether the force returned by Joint::GetForce() includes only the force my plug-in has applied to the wheel, or whether it also contains the force applied, for example, by a curb that the wheel has hit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9585/does-joint::getforce()-return-the-sum-of-all-forces-on-the-joint?/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Joint::GetForce()` has not been implemented, you will get back 0 in all instances.  It might be worth a [new ticket/patch](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac) to add an internal variable in each joint object to keep track of total forces added via `ODEJoint::SetForce(...)` calls and return the value when `GetForce()` is called.

Alternatively, you can also get back ODE's computed total force and torque applied on a body by calling `ODEJoint::GetBodyForce(unsigned int)` and `ODEJoint::GetBodyTorque(unsigned int)`.  The returned wrench will be the total force/torque applied to the body at each time step update due to gravity and constraints.  Set `<provideFeedback>True</provideFeedback>` flag in the joint definition XML block to enable this feature.  Please note that the returned value may need to be time averaged to be useful if the simulation is jittery.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-07-26**:
Does this still apply in fuerte?  Trying to use Link::GetRelativeForce(), GetWorldForce(), or Joint::GetForce gives me zeros while Joint::GetLinkForce() and GetLinkTorque() give seg faults...

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-07-26**:
also, is there an example of how to use this somewhere?